# Attach and detach touch item helper to a recycler view

Tags: android

I have a setup where there is a vertical recycler view (VR) where the items are swipable (left only) and each item also contain a horizontal recycler view (HR). I have a check in the adapter viewholder of the VR to see if the HR is touched.

```
horizontalRecycler.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
                switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // The user just touched the screen
                        scrollingCheck.onScrollCheck(true);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // The touch just ended
                        scrollingCheck.onScrollCheck(false);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

Via an interface, I am passing the touch action to see if the horizontal recycler is touched:

```
interface OnScrollingCheck {
    void onScrollCheck(boolean scrolling);
}
```

And in the parent fragment which contains the VR, I implement the interface listener method to attach and detach an item touch helper for a swipe action on an item of the VR:

```
@Override
public void onScrollCheck(boolean scrolling) {
    if (scrolling) {
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this, false);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mealplanRecycler);
    } else {
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this, true);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mealplanRecycler);
    }
}
```

And here's the custom implementation of simple item touch helper:

```
public class RecyclerTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

private final RecyclerTouchHelperListener listener;
private boolean swipeAllowed;
private static final String TAG = RecyclerTouchHelper.class.getSimpleName();

public RecyclerTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerTouchHelperListener listener, boolean swipeAllowed) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.listener = listener;
    this.swipeAllowed = swipeAllowed;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildDrawOver(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    Log.d(TAG, "isItemViewSwipeEnabled: " + swipeAllowed);
    return swipeAllowed;
}

@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public interface RecyclerTouchHelperListener {
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working. When I run the app, I try to swipe the VR item and it won't swipe but the HR scrolls fine. But once I let go of the HR, I am always able to swipe even when I try to scroll the HR.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The idea is that there should be NO swipe action if the HR is scrolled. And as soon as it is not being scrolled then the swipe action should be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get the parent view of the horizontal recyclerview and disable touch intercept event like this:

```
horizontalRecycler.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
            return false;
        });
```